# How can I add Delicious bookmarks in IE 10 desktop?

Tags: windows-8, javascript, internet-explorer-10

It is clear from the Delicious tools page that there is no add-on for internet explorer and it provides a bookmarklet. I managed to get this into the favourites list by editing an existing Favourite (there is no toolbar to drag bookmarklets to, even the desktop version!)

However it does not seem to execute properly, nothing happens when clicking on the bookmarklet.

Are bookmarlets disabled for IE10? If not, why can't I use my Delicious bookmarklet? Are there any other options for delicious users on IE10?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you bring this issue up with the originator of the Delicious bookmarking system.  No doubt that the add-on does not successfully integrate with IE10 and needs some work by the author to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The bookmarklets now work on the latest version of IE

Here's the url: https://delicious.com/tools